# RichTextBox: different color for the first character

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a RichTextBox (`Name="txtGoTo"`) in WPF and I need only the first character colored in red (while the rest in the default black).

This is what I tried (got it online), but it doesn't work:

```
    Dim rtb As RichTextBox = txtGoTo
    Dim Text As String = New TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text) Then

        Dim RangeAisle As TextPointer = rtb.Document.ContentStart
        Dim RangeShelf As TextPointer = rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(1)

        Dim tr As New TextRange(RangeAisle, RangeShelf)
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `rtb.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(1)` doesn't return first letter. It would be more like index of `3`

Code below will get position of first letter and changed to red.

```
Dim position As TextPointer = rtb.Document.ContentStart
While position IsNot Nothing
    If position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) = TextPointerContext.Text Then
        Dim start As TextPointer = position.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward)
        Dim [end] As TextPointer = position.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Backward)
        New TextRange(start, [end]).ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red)
        Exit While
    End If
    position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)
End While
```

Comment: Visual Studio gives me a Syntax error under New in `New TextRange(start, [end]).ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red)`